# Symfony project can't find UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using `UserInterface` in a `getToken` method that receive the user registered and generates him a token, but when I send the data (in Postman) I get the error:

> Cannot autowire argument `$user` of
> `"App\Controller\AuthController::getTokenUser()"`: it references
> interface `"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface"` but no
> such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this
> interface?

Edit: I'd implemented UserInterface in every class where I needed it. Sorry for not mentioning it

The method for getting the token:

```
public function getTokenUser(UserInterface $user, JWTTokenManagerInterface $JWTManager)
{
    return new JsonResponse(['token' => $JWTManager->create($user)]);
}
```

Route for the method:

```
 api_login_check:
             path: /api/login_check
             controller: App\Controller\AuthController::getTokenUser
```

Comment: probably, because you have no user when sending data via postman ;o) there are some possible factors, which none of us can tell you without you giving some information about your security setup and AuthController.

Comment: User's are entities and generally not considered to be services.  If you use "bin/console debug:container UserInterface" you will see that there is no such service and thus you cannot inject it.  If your controller extends AbstractController then just use $this->getUser().  If not then follow: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service

Comment: It might, emphasis on the work might, be possible to define a UserInterface service as a factory which in turn would allow your original approach to work.  Seems like I read something about that somewhere but can't find it.  It would take a bit of experimenting especially to see what happens if the user is not yet available in the request cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement your class User with UserInterface in `App\Entity\User`

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface {
```

Comment: It was implemented in the beginning, sorry for not mentioning it. UserInterface is implemented in every class where I need it, but I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

you simply  forgot to add a body to that request

```
{"username":"","password":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution on this, here is what you can try.
I have tested it with multiple endpoints across multiple projects.

If you are testing it in postman whatever body type, try passing it as a JSON string. it will work.
[status code 200 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z85R.png) 
If you are requesting in raw text format, you will receive the above mentioned error. it may work for register method, but for the getToken() method it doesn't work.
[status code 500 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ABh.png)
Screenshots attached on both cases.